# How to protect github-token while using chrome-extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, access-token, github-api

I want to create **chrome extension**, which interacts with **github** repository.

---

1: User click button

2: API creates new file and inserts submitted data

3: API reads all existing files and calculates specific data

4: API sends back calculations to user

*(All commands launched automatic from extension)*

---

*Can someone explain:*

If it's possible to use `Personal access tokens` from github, but also `lock access` for outsiders?

I mean.. token can be visible for everyone, but **Github-API should work only if used with chrome extension**.

---

*At this moment completed only two steps..*

- Created 'machine user'
- Invited him to my repository and gave 'repo' permissions

*Next steps unknown..*

- ?? Create *Personal access tokens* or *OAuth apps* to get access to API?
- ?? Somehow give info to github about my extension, and allow all actions only from this extension

Comment: The source code of an extension can be viewed trivially either after installing it or by using tools like crxviewer and you can't upload obfuscated code to the web store and anyway it's possible to use devtools or simply intercept the request in Fiddler/Charles/WireShark. The only solution is to make a separate site/service to which your users will log in from your extension, and that service will talk to github.

Comment: I don't have any server.. that's why i want to use public github repository.
I don't care if code is visible.

And critical part - users should not use any logins. Connections should be through extension automatically.


Should be method to allow API calls only from this extension.. because extension have unique ID..

Comment: In that case you can't protect the token because anyone can copy and use it.

Comment: Ok..
I allow (for hackers..) to create any file in repository, but not allow to delete or edit data.
It's possible?

Which permissions i should enable for "Personal access token"

If it's "gist" .. It have full permissions? I can't exclude delete/edit ?